# Spring Boot application join doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entity, joincolumn

My join between `user` and `authority` isn't seem to be working.

Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    // define fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
...


@Entity
@Table(name="authorities")
public class Authority {    

    @EmbeddedId
    private AuthorityId id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="member_email", referencedColumnName="email", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;
    
    public Authority() {
        
    }

    public Authority(AuthorityId id, User user, String email, String authority) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public AuthorityId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(AuthorityId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return id.getEmail();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.id.setEmail(email);
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return id.getAuthority();
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.id.setAuthority(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Authority [user=" + user + ", email=" + id.getEmail() + ", authority=" + id.getAuthority() + "]";
    }

}
```

I tried adding `referencedColumnName=email` to my authorities `JoinColumn` but with that I'm unable to login. Could it be something to do with my `Serializable` class?

```
@Embeddable
public class AuthorityId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="authority")
    private String authority;
    
    public AuthorityId() {
        
    }

    public AuthorityId(String email, String authority) {
        this.email = email;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AuthorityId)) return false;
        AuthorityId that = (AuthorityId) o;
        return Objects.equals(getEmail(), that.getEmail()) &&
                Objects.equals(getAuthority(), that.getAuthority());
    }
 
    // equals/hashCode based on all data(email and authority)
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getEmail(), getAuthority());
    }

}
```

**Additional information**

This is the error when I remove `insertable=false, updatable=false`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventRepository' defined in com.paulcarron.clubmanager.dao.EventRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.Authority column: member_email (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.paulcarron.clubmanager.ClubmanagerApplication.main(ClubmanagerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.Authority column: member_email (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.Authority column: member_email (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.paulcarron.clubmanager.entity.Authority column: member_email (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:880) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:902) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:634) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Here is a diagram of my tables:

[image]

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your current mapping assume that the `authorities.member_email` is a foreign key to the `users.id`. Is it true?

Comment: No. It's a foreign key to `users.email`.

Comment: So, you should add `referencedColumnName=email`. What exception do you get after that?

Comment: Could you explain also why do you use `insertable=false, updatable=false` in your `@JoinColumn`? Is it deliberate choice?

Comment: Sorry, `referencedColumnName` doesn't throw an exception. I can't get logged in with it though. I updated the question and if I can add more info I'll do so later.

Comment: `insertable` and `updatable` were added to resolve an issue I was having when implementing `AuthorityId`.

Comment: I do not see any problem that can be solved here by adding `insertable=false, updatable=false`. So, could you try to remove it. It would be nice to see ER diagram of your tables. Enabling sql traces could help to find a problem (see `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql`, `hibernate.use_sql_comments` properties)

Comment: Show also what exactly query or persist/merge action cause a problem.

Comment: Additional info added to question. I'll add the sql traces when I get them working.

Comment: Could you please provide full code of your `Authority` entity. According to the exception stack trace you use  `member_email`  more that one time but I do not see it from the provided code. Also you use the `@Column(name="email")` in the `AuthorityId` but I do not see the `email` column in your ER diagram for the `authorities` table.

Comment: Entire authorities has been added.

Answer (score 0):

The following mapping is worked for me:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authority
{
   private AuthorityId id;
   private User user;
   
   public Authority()
   {
   }

   public Authority(String email, String authority)
   {
      this.id = new AuthorityId();
      this.id.setEmail(email);
      this.id.setAuthority(authority);
   }
   
   @EmbeddedId
   public AuthorityId getId()
   {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(AuthorityId id)
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "member_email", referencedColumnName = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   public User getUser()
   {
      return user;
   }
   public void setUser(User user)
   {
      this.user = user;
   }
}

@Embeddable
public class AuthorityId implements Serializable
{
   private String email;
   private String authority;
   
   public AuthorityId()
   {
   }

   @Column(name = "member_email")
   public String getEmail()
   {
      return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(String email)
   {
      this.email = email;
   }

   @Column(name = "authority")
   public String getAuthority()
   {
      return authority;
   }
   public void setAuthority(String authority)
   {
      this.authority = authority;
   }

   // equals and hashCode
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable
{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private List<Authority> authorities;
   
   public User()
   {
      authorities = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   public Integer getId()
   {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(Integer id)
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @NaturalId
   @Column(name = "email")
   public String getEmail()
   {
      return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(String email)
   {
      this.email = email;
   }

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   public List<Authority> getAuthorities()
   {
      return authorities;
   }
   public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities)
   {
      this.authorities = authorities;
   }
   
   public void addAuthority(Authority auth)
   {
      authorities.add(auth);
      auth.setUser(this);
   }
}
```

and simple persist action:

```java
String email = "emeil2@gmail.com";

User user = new User();
user.setEmail(email);
     
Authority auth1 = new Authority(email, "auth2");
Authority auth2 = new Authority(email, "auth3");
Authority auth3 = new Authority(email, "auth4");
      
user.addAuthority(auth1);
user.addAuthority(auth2);
user.addAuthority(auth3);
      
em.persist(user);
```

will generate the following sql queries:

```
/* insert com.my.hibernate.entities.User */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.USERS (email) 
values (?)

/* insert com.sternkn.hibernate.entities.Authority */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.AUTHORITIES (authority, member_email)
values (?, ?)

/* insert com.sternkn.hibernate.entities.Authority */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.AUTHORITIES (authority, member_email)
values (?, ?)

/* insert com.sternkn.hibernate.entities.Authority */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.AUTHORITIES (authority, member_email)
values (?, ?)
```

It was tested with hibernate 5.4.10.Final